# How to delete checked items with one delete button

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to make a delete button that deletes the checked items. Means one  master button to delete all the checked items. I made a master checkbox that checks all the values. Now I want to make a master button that would delete the checked values. Here is my code. I am new in laravel please help me. Sorry for my bad english.

```
@extends('footer')
@extends('header')

@section('body')
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Retrieve data|Std view</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('public/css/style.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('public/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('public/js/jQuery.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>

    @if(session()->has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <h3> {{ session()->get('success') }} </h3>
    </div>

    @endif 

<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">

    <h2 style="color: green">This Is View Form</h2>
    <a href = "insert" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</a>

//HERE IS MY MASTER DELETE BUTTON.
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"  >Delete</button><br><br>


    <table border="1" id="customers">
        <tr>
            <th>
//Here is my checkbox inside the loop.
    <input type="checkbox" id="master" onchange="checkall(this);"> All
            </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Update</th>
            <th>Delete</th>

        </tr>

        @foreach($data as $value)
        <tr>

            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="sub_chk_{{ $value->id }}"  value="{{ $value->id }}">
            </td>
            <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->email }}</td>
<td><a href="edit/{{$value->id}}" class="btn btn-primary" >Edit</a></td>

//THIS DELETE BUTTON FOR SINGLE DELETE FUNCTION

<td><a href="delete/{{$value->id}}" onclick='ConfirmDelete()' class="btn btn-danger" >Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    </form><br>

    {{ $data->links() }}

</div>  

</body>

</html>
@endsection

<script>

    function checkall(obj) {
        var selectedIds = [];
        if(obj.checked){
     $('input:checkbox').not(obj).prop('checked', 'checked');
     $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

    if($this.is(":checked")){
        selectedIds.push($this.attr("value"));
    console.log(selectedIds);
    }
     })
        }
        else{
     $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
        }
 }

function ConfirmDelete()
{
  var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
  if (x)
      return true;
  else
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all get array of ids of checked checkbox, and then in controller use those ids to delete your data. for this first give name to input type checkbox (inside your foreach loop), like this,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" class="sub_chk_{{ $value->id }}"  value="{{ $value->id }}">
```

Then create new route for form action.
And then in that controller function write logic to delete data. like,

```
function delete(Request $request){
     Model::whereIn('id',$request['ids'])->delete();
}
```

thats it.

Comment: bro here is my delete function can i make changes in it or make new function for this  purpose my code is given bloew

Comment: public function destroy($id)
       {
          $query = DB::table('student')
          ->where('id', $id)->delete();
          return redirect()->route('std_view',$query)->with('success', 'Delete Successfully!');
           
       }

Comment: BRO I NEED IT FOR MASTER BUTTON THAT IS OUTSIDE THE LOOP

Comment: HERE IS MY ALL ROUTE                                                                                                       Route::get('insert','StudInsertController@insertform');
Route::post('create','StudInsertController@insert');
Route::get('view','StudInsertController@retrieve')->name('std_view');
Route::get('edit/{id}','StudInsertController@showid');
Route::post('post/{id}','StudInsertController@update')->name('update.student');
Route::get('delete/{id}','StudInsertController@destroy');

Comment: sorry for late reply.  The destroy function with $id as param is to delete specific row only. so you need to make another route and function since you need two seperate action (one to delete single specific row and another for multiple selected rows)

Comment: Bro i also check you posted code but it not working. I gave some errors. I make a new route. Also make new function in controller my function is running without any errors but it is not deleting the values . HERE IS FUNCTION CODE                   public function delete(Request $request)
       {
            $ids = $request->ids;
           DB::table('student')->whereIn('id',explode(",", $ids))->delete();
           return redirect()->route('std_view')->with('success', 'Delete Successfully!');

        } ROUTE    Route::get('delete','StudInsertController@delete');

Comment: HERE IS MY MSTER BUTTON CODE  <a href="delete" onclick='ConfirmDelete()' class="btn btn-danger" >Delete</a><br><br>

Comment: it should be Route::post method

Comment: Bro Now I AM USING ROUTE WITH POST METHOD //HERE IS ROUTE ==>Route::post('delete','StudInsertController@delete'); AND I ALSO USE POST METHOD IN MY FORM //HERE IS MY FORM==><form action="" method="post"> //HERE IS MY FUNCTION==> public function delete(Request $request)
       {
           DB::table('student')->whereIn('id',$request['checkbox'])->delete();
           return redirect()->route('std_view')->with('success', 'Delete Successfully!');

Comment: //WHEN WE RUN  IT  THROW BACK AN ERROR==>The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: Did you provide delete route url in form action action=""?

Comment: YES HERE IS MY CODE OF ROUTE==>Route::post('selected/items','StudInsertController@delete_selected')->name('selected'); HERE IS CODE OF MY FORM ==><form action="{{ route('selected') }}" method="POST"> BUT IT IS THROWING SAME ERROR ==> MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: DELETE BUTTON CODE IS HERE==>><a href="{{ url('selected/items') }}" onclick='ConfirmDelete()'  name="" class="btn btn-danger" >Delete</a>

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH BRO I DONE IT. BY USING BUTTON TAG INSTED OF ANCHOR <a></a>. THANK YOU VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY MUCH

Comment: glad you did it..dnt forget to upvote the answer. :)